# Phrasing Baseball Box Scores

Tags: php, mysql, screen-scraping

I have a unique problem, I need to pull specific attributes for every game that is being played every 5 minutes, the two main issues I have are:

1. Phrasing data from a website that displays it interactively i.e. MLB.com, ESPN, CBS Sports.
2. Finding a source that would perhaps show the box scores that are updated live and in a text format.

I have done significant Googling as well as looking at possible solutions for scraping data off of MLB and CBS Sports. I havn't had such luck, it's a bit difficult right now because I don't have any fresh data to play with however I've been looking for possible solutions and havn't came to any resolution.

To my knowledge there isn't an open database that I can query that contains live updates scores otherwise I could piggyback off of that or obtain a similar system.

Comment: If there was a service that stored that data I'm sure they would charge $$$ for it. As for scraping sites, there's not really a generic way, at least that I'm aware of, that can just hit a url and know what data to pull. You'll need to download the html and use regex or other method to find the data. Also, if the site changes even slightly, you'll have to fix and rebuild.

Comment: If the service provides the data I would need, I'd be willing to pay for it for this project. I'll look into Regex but sites are always rebuilding, so that could potentially break it. With this project, I would need a solid solution.

Comment: [Wolfram appears to have ancient data](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=seattle+seahawks) but this sounds like something that _would_ fit their business model. Give them a call and see how much it would cost.

Comment: I didn't even give Wolfram a thought, I didn't know they took requests.

Comment: @MikeGags Here is something that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643753/does-anybody-know-of-a-real-time-sports-scores-stats-web-service Also, if you do find a pay service I would think they would give you API access, so no need for scraping.

Answer (score 1):

check out this forum question on another site.  Looks like there are a few out there that will allow you to get csv's of their data.  Not sure how much of it could be automated.

http://ask.metafilter.com/120399/MLB-API

Another is http://www.baseball-reference.com/ I'm not sure if they do box scores but they have stats on all the players, games, etc.  They might have something you can use as well.

Finally you could check out http://www.strat-o-matic.com/ they might have something or be willing to create an API for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice on Yahoo, they get their stats from [STATS LLC](http://www.stats.com/index.asp).  I have no idea what it costs, but you should check-out their [real-time](http://www.stats.com/real_time.asp) data delivery service.

Answer (score 0):

Scrape the MLB gameday server. It is updated in realtime during games. If you want the boxscore, scrape [boxscore.xml](http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2013/month_10/day_30/gid_2013_10_30_slnmlb_bosmlb_1/boxscore.xml) (for example)